# Циклический битовый сдвиг всех элементов bytearray Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, шифрование

Есть байтовый массив. Для шифра Магма необходимо циклически сдвинуть по битого все элементы влево на 11, т.е. первый бит первого байта становиться последним битом последнего байта.
Единственное, что я придумал, это перевести в бинарный формат, выровнять по границе байта(8 бит) и склеить получив строку -

```
b = "11010000101110001101000010110010"
```

*двоичное представление массива - bytearray(b'\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2')*

и через срезы сдвинуть

```
b[11:] + b[:11]
```

*Вывод соответственно - 11000110 10000101 10010110 10000101*

Что то мне подсказывает, что есть намного более лучшее решение. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Да как-то нет. Способ через срезы лучший. Можно, конечно, выдумать что-то интересное, но этот способ наиболее понятный и быстрый.

Comment: Ну по идее можно подумать, посчитать, сколько байт должны переехать и сколько бит, если у нас данные в `bytearray`. Сложно будет, но можно сделать эффективно. Хотя это каждый байт придётся сдвигать, если остаток от 8 будет. Не факт, что это будет эффективно.

Comment: А в вашем bytearray всегда 4 байта?

Comment: да, блок в 32 бита

Comment: `i = int.from_bytes(b'\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2', 'big'); print(bin((i << 11) % (2**32) | (i >> 21)))`

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ответ с [английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63767548/8324991) для данных в `int`:

```py
def ISHFTC(n, d, N):  
    return ((n << d) % (1 << N)) | (n >> (N - d))
```

Где:

- `n` - число, которое двигаем влево
- `d` - на сколько бит
- `N` - сколькибитовая у нас арифметика (после какого бита числа данные должны переехать вправо)

Comment: Это вроде сдвиг каждого элемента по отдельности, нет? Мне нужно что бы байты из списка в связке сдвигались

Comment: Ну у вас же фиксированный блок данных? Превратите его в `int` предварительно и потом обратно. )  Но вообще нужно проверять, может через текстовое представление и быстрее будет.

Comment: Большое спасибо